# Download Dash package through anaconda :raised this error KeyError('pkgs_dirs')

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, plotly-dash

I wanna to download the Dash framework through anaconda but this error raised

```
**environment variables:
conda info could not be constructed.
KeyError('pkgs_dirs')**
```

Note: I add the Scripts directory path in the **PATH environment variable.**

So, any can help me to solve this?

Comment: If you don't have a `.condarc` file in your home dir, run `conda config --add channels conda-forge` to create one.

Answer (score 0):

run "conda info" and "conda config --show-sources" locate where the .condarc files are located. These files configure shell behaviors. You can add entries to these files via this command:

`conda config --file C:\Users\username\.condarc --add pkgs_dirs C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs`

Comment: I already try to use this commands but I face the same error

Comment: This error raised when I type Conda info (AttributeError: 'YamlRawParameter' object has no attribute 'typify')